# Deploy springboot jar on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, spring-boot

I want to deploy the spring-boot jar on AWS . I don't know how to proceed with the embedded Tomcat . There is a way using war but i want to use the embedded Tomcat . Please tell me the basic steps here .

Also , i want to know how can I use Jenkins and just push the code to github and the Jenkins job will deploy it to AWS .

Comment: Not sure if you are still looking out but lately I created a CXF based springboot webeservice and deployed on AWS using the aws beanstalk service. I did a 2 part blog where first part talks about creating a springboot cxf webservice and deploying to aws manually. Second part talks about how you can automate the whole deployment using tools like aws cloudformation, and ansible playbooks. Part I Link: http://amansbhatia.blogspot.in/2016/12/creating-springboot-based-rest-web.html Part II Link: http://amansbhatia.blogspot.in/2016/12/creating-springboot-based-rest-web_31.html Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 3):

It's good to read bit more before asking but there are many ways to do it. The fat jar you get when you do `mvn clean package` on your project has embedded tomcat. Very basic way to run it is upload that jar on AWS, provided it has java installed just run that jar using

```
'java -jar your-app-jar.1.0.jar'
```

Now you can automate that whole flow, one thing that worked good for me on one of my project is to use docker, the flow being:

> Github -> Private Docker Repository (https://hub.docker.com/) -> Tutum (https://www.tutum.co/) -> Live app

I will let you figure the details out. As each of these requires some reading and setting up. If you don't want to do all this setup, you can use things like Heroku which has a nice support for Spring boot apps and deployment is just a matter of pushing code to github.